# Generating unique logon id failing when loop reaches 9 in sql 2012

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to generate unique logoid for each user in SQL 2012 but it fails when the loop reaches 9. The logonid takes the first letter of forename,surname and the trailer which is added one. It fails when end is 9 because all logoid after this are not unique.  Kindly see the code below and tell me what's wrong in the code

```
  create database passwords
    go
    use passwords
    go

    create table Users
   (
   id int identity(1,1),
   forename varchar(80),
  surname varchar(40)
   )
  go
  INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('Peter','Kimani'),('Paul','Kimani'),
 ('Pius','Kimani'),('Pyuwa','Kimani'),
 ('Poetry','Kimani'),('Pig','Kimani'),('Paul','Kimani'),
 ('Pk','Kimani'),('Paul','Kimani'),('Petra','Kimani'),
 ('Paul','Kimani'),('Popeye','Kimani'),('George','Onyango')

   go
   --select * from Users
   go
   alter table Users add
   logonid varchar(40),
   Usr_pwd varchar(40) default 'p@$$w0rd'
   go
   --trim any spaces in the data. (OPTIONAL)

   update Users set surname = LTRIM(rtrim(surname)),
  forename = LTRIM(rtrim(forename))
  go

  declare @fname varchar(40), @surname varchar(40), @logonid varchar(40),
  @pass varchar(40), @min int, @max int, @trailer varchar(10), @end int

  -- there are 2 ways to do this. as below Or
  select @min = MIN(id), @max = MAX(id) from Users
  /*
 set @min = (select min(id) from Users)
 set @max = (select max(id) from Users)
 */
 set @fname = '' set @surname = '' set @pass = 'p@$$w0rd' 
 set @logonid = ''

while @min <= @max--loops through from smallest to biggest
begin
  select @fname = forename, @surname = surname from Users where ID = @min

  set @logonid = SUBSTRING(@fname,1,1)+@surname

  if not exists(select '1' from Users where logonid = @logonid)
        update Users set logonid = @logonid, Usr_pwd = @pass 
        where ID    =    @min
  else

  begin
        set @logonid = (select top 1 logonid from Users 
        where logonid like @logonid+'%' order by logonid desc)
        set @trailer = RIGHT(@logonid,1)
        if ISNUMERIC(@trailer) = 1
        begin
              set @end = @trailer
              set @end = @end+1
              set @logonid = SUBSTRING(@logonid, 1, len(@logonid)-1)
              print @end print @trailer print @min
              set @logonid = @logonid+CAST(@end as varchar)
              print @logonid
              update Users set logonid = @logonid, Usr_pwd = @pass 
             where ID = @min
        end
        else
        begin
              set @logonid = @logonid+'1'
              update Users set logonid = @logonid, Usr_pwd = @pass
           where ID = @min
        end
        end
    set @fname = '' set @surname = '' set @pass = 'p@$$w0rd' 
    set @logonid = ''
    set @min = @min+1
       end 

    --use passwords
    --select * from Users
```

The output

```
 id  forenamesurname logoid      Usr_pwd
 1  Peter   Kimani  PKimani     p@$$w0rd
 2  Paul    Kimani  PKimani1    p@$$w0rd
 3  Pius    Kimani  PKimani2    p@$$w0rd
 4  Pyuwa   Kimani  PKimani3    p@$$w0rd
 5  Poetry  Kimani  PKimani4    p@$$w0rd
 6  Pig     Kimani  PKimani5    p@$$w0rd
 7  Paul    Kimani  PKimani6    p@$$w0rd
 8  Pk      Kimani  PKimani7    p@$$w0rd
 9  Paul    Kimani  PKimani8    p@$$w0rd
 10 Petra   Kimani  PKimani9    p@$$w0rd
 11 Paul    Kimani  PKimani10   p@$$w0rd
 12 Popeye  Kimani  PKimani10   p@$$w0rd
 13 George  Onyango GOnyango    p@$$w0rd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an incredibly arcane way to do this.  How about:

```
select @logon_suffix = coalesce(max(cast(substr(logon, patindex('%[0-9]%', logon + '0'), 100) as int) + 1, 1)
from users u
where logon like @base_logon + '[0-9]%;
```

This should calculate the suffix for you without a loop.

Note:  I wouldn't represent the duplicate values this way.  I would use zero-padded suffixes, such as 0001, 0002, and so on.  That makes the logic for incrementing them much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to do this much to generate the `Login` for each user. Use the auto generated `ID` column to generate the `Login`

You just need this

```
ALTER TABLE Users
  ADD logonid  as  Substring(forename, 1, 1) + surname + cast(id as varchar(50)) PERSISTED
  , Usr_pwd VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 'p@$$w0rd'
```

Creating you `computed column` with `PERSISTED` option will save you some time when you perform `select` on this table

```
update Users set Usr_pwd = 'p@$$w0rd'
```

When I `Select` the table

```
SELECT *
FROM   Users
```

**Result :**

```
+----+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| id | forename | surname |  logonid   | Usr_pwd  |
+----+----------+---------+------------+----------+
|  1 | Peter    | Kimani  | PKimani1   | p@$$w0rd |
|  2 | Paul     | Kimani  | PKimani2   | p@$$w0rd |
|  3 | Pius     | Kimani  | PKimani3   | p@$$w0rd |
|  4 | Pyuwa    | Kimani  | PKimani4   | p@$$w0rd |
|  5 | Poetry   | Kimani  | PKimani5   | p@$$w0rd |
|  6 | Pig      | Kimani  | PKimani6   | p@$$w0rd |
|  7 | Paul     | Kimani  | PKimani7   | p@$$w0rd |
|  8 | Pk       | Kimani  | PKimani8   | p@$$w0rd |
|  9 | Paul     | Kimani  | PKimani9   | p@$$w0rd |
| 10 | Petra    | Kimani  | PKimani10  | p@$$w0rd |
| 11 | Paul     | Kimani  | PKimani11  | p@$$w0rd |
| 12 | Popeye   | Kimani  | PKimani12  | p@$$w0rd |
| 13 | George   | Onyango | GOnyango13 | p@$$w0rd |
+----+----------+---------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: thank you for your help. This also is working but i have to use the loop. How can i make the loop to work?

Comment: @WannabeJavaGeek - Why are you opting for harder option when there is a much simpler way..

Comment: @WannabeJavaGeek - To fix your current approach check Gordan's answer